# How can I do a match of the type "if ($variable[any_index] =~ m/'string'/) {print $variable[next_index];}"?

Tags: perl

Please, how can I do a match like this:

```
my @variable = split;
if ($variable[any_index] =~ m/'string'/) {print $variable[next_index];}
```

Is there a simple way to specify $variable[any_index]?

Is it possible to use some kind of 'look ahead' in the statement 'print $variable[next_index]'?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not very clear what you're asking for.  Are you attempting to find any entry in @variable that matches 'string'?  If so, look into `grep`.

Comment: So, if you have a match at index 'n', then you want to print the value at the index 'n + 1'?  Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct Paul and David!

Answer (score 4):

```
print $variable[$_] for grep { $variable[$_-1] =~ /'string'/ } 1..$#variable
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( my ($idx) = grep $variable[$_] =~ /string/, 0..$#variable ) {
    print "$variable[$idx+1]\n";
}
```

If you want to print for all matches,

```
for my $idx ( grep $variable[$_] =~ /string/, 0..$#variable ) {
    print "$variable[$idx+1]\n";
}
```

Comment: What if there is more than one match?

Comment: Calls print once, like in your pseudocode. Added version that prints for all matches.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm testing it!

Answer (score 1):

Don't get me wrong, but grep and map has always scared me. This is my way of doing it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my @array = qw/hello world hello there hello you/;
foreach (0..$#array) 
{
    print $array[$_ + 1]."\n" if $array[$_] =~ /llo/;
}
```

this will print:

```
world
there
you
```